# Sort data by priorities

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a SortableList where you can organize your order to make filter priorities.

like that:

```
[
    0: "Fruits",
    1: "Legumes",
    2: "Example1",
]
```

then I have some data like this:

```
[
    {
        id: 0,
        _source: {
                     someOtherProps,
                     source: "Fruits"
                 }
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        _source: {
                    someOtherProps, 
                    source: "Example1"
                 }
    },
    .... blablabla
]
```

I want to sort the data by the source, respecting the order priorities.

I try to use the sort() function, but I don't have any ideas how I could do that.

In this example: I will have all my data object sorted firstly by the source "Fruits", then "Legumes" then "Example1".

Comment: *"I try to use the sort() function, but I don't have any ideas how I could do that."* **Show** what you tried. If you didn't succeed in actually trying anything with it, do more research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object for the sort order and take the delta as result for the callback.

```js
var order = { Fruits: 1, Legumes: 2, Example1: 3 },
    data = [{ id: 0, _source: { source: "Fruits" } }, { id: 1, _source: { source: "Example1" } }];
    
data.sort((a, b) => order[a._source.source] - order[b._source.source]);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```